# Using Regex in Python to Delete MongoDB databases with "expn" at end of name

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

Given the number of questions on regex on StackOverFlow, I am sorry to add yet another, but I can't seem to figure out the error in my script.  It is supposed to run through all the collections in my database and take a conditional action based on whether they contain the string "_Clean" at the end.

I'm pretty sure I'm using the wrong regex.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.son import SON
import re

db = MongoClient().guns
pattern = re.compile("(?!)(_Clean)\Z")

for collection in db.collection_names():
    if pattern.match(str(collection)):
        print(str(collection))
        print("No, I should be dropped")
    else:
        print("Yay, I am clean")
        print(str(collection))
```

The output I receive is:

```
Yay, I am clean
Accidental_Injuries_Clean
Yay, I am clean
Massshootings_Clean
Yay, I am clean
Accidental_Injuries_Teens_Clean
Yay, I am clean
Officer_Involved_Shootings_Clean
Yay, I am clean
Accidental_Deaths_Children
Yay, I am clean
Accidental_Injuries_Children_Clean
Yay, I am clean
```

Thank you all so much for your time, and I appreciate any suggestions you may offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you really need a regular expression here.  You can just use basic string slicing:

```
dbs = ['Accidental_Injuries_Clean',
'Massshootings_Clean',
'Accidental_Injuries_Teens_Clean',
'Officer_Involved_Shootings_Clean',
'Accidental_Deaths_Children',
'Accidental_Injuries_Children_Clean']

for db in dbs:
  if db[-6:] == '_Clean':
    print('Delete: ', db)
```

Output:

```
Delete:  Accidental_Injuries_Clean
Delete:  Massshootings_Clean
Delete:  Accidental_Injuries_Teens_Clean
Delete:  Officer_Involved_Shootings_Clean
Delete:  Accidental_Injuries_Children_Clean
```

Just a note, your current regex isn't working because you are using negative lookahead for the string you want to find.  Here is one that works:

[`^.*_Clean$`](https://regex101.com/r/C6Qfjp/1/)